# Visual Cues for Cancelling Ordered Item and Deleting Added Product

Tags: e-commerce, edit, order

We have a feature under development entitled "Edit Order" and one of its feature is the ability to remove a newly added item and to cancel an item that were already placed. I am planning to use an "x" button for deleting a newly added product and "Cancel" text for item(s) that were already placed in order. But our stakeholders wanted to have the "Cancel" text to be an icon. Can you give me a good suggestion of what icon to use? or maybe a better way of implementing this concern? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For items in the Cart, if it is a Mobile App you can go with the **"X"** button, and if it is a Website or an Application **"Remove"** button or a **"Remove"** Text (Underlined) is preferred.

And for the placed orders, you can go with the **"Cancel"** or **"Cancel Order"** button. Also, make sure to give a pop-up warning to the user when clicking either of these above actions.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!